# concurrent queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to design a queue which could be simultaneously accessed by multiple read/write threads. I prefer using 2 mutexes, one apiece for read and write. Doing write is simple enough, lock the write mutex, append data, unlock and you are done.

The issue is with read. If there's no data in the in queue I'd like my thread to wait till data is available. 1 obvious way to do this is to acquire read mutex and keep polling the queue every N clock cycles but this is obviously not the best approach. Which brings me to condition variables. Does anybody have any good resource which discusses blocking queue implementation in C++ with condition variables (preferably pthreads based)?

Specifically, I see the following issues:

1. Once a write is done, the writer thread would do a pthread_cond_signal that data exists but how does it know that some reader thread is waiting? It is illegal to call pthread_cond_signal unless there is a pthread_cond_wait.
2. Is it okay to call pthread_cond_broadcast instead of pthread_cond_signal? Perhaps that might circumvent the issue with pthread_cond_wait. Also this seems more logical as multiple reader threads is definitely a real possibility.
3. It also appears that the reader and writer threads must be locked with the same mutex to make use of the condition variable. If this is true then we have a severe problem.

Comment: Why do you think #3 is "a severe problem?"

Comment: @pilcrow The problem's severe 'cause by design I want read/write threads to have parallel access to the queue. If there's a single mutex then parallel read/write won't happen.

Comment: as Jim Lewis points out it's not clear that you have any *read* threads, merely two kinds of *writers* (consumer and producer).  In this case, `pthread_cond_wait` will atomically release its mutex during the wait, so that producers (and arriving consumers, for that matter) don't block on the mutex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 12-3 of [this C++ threading blog post](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/C++/Making_A_Resource_Thread-Safe.htm) should give you a reference implementation, but I think you're dangerously close to success on your own. Addressing your specific concerns:

1. It is *not* illegal to signal when there are no waiters. It's totally legitimate, and you can leverage that fact. (Where did you read this, btw?)
2. `pthread_cond_broadcast` causes one major problem: the *herd of elephants* charge, where all *n* threads awake and start pulling memory between caches even though only one of them can possibly make forward progress. It will work, but it's not as efficient.
3. You can signal from anywhere, even from a thread that never has to deal with the mutex in question. Your `pthread_cond_wait` calls must release the read mutex; that is the only requirement, and that's the only mutex that ever needs to interact with the condition variable.

Following from #3, there is one major problem with your idea: **The writer thread must lock *both* the read and write mutexes.** If it does not, what happens when the queue size is 1 and you have a reader and a writer acting at the same time?

Comment: That does sound like a non-optimal reference as it doesn't show the use condition variables like the OP wants.

Comment: True! I'm having trouble finding a reference that uses both read/write mutexes _and_ condition variables. Arpan's reference demonstrates condition variables rather well.

Comment: There's an example here: http://asgaard.homelinux.org/svn/cpp/threadqueue .  Using a read and a write mutex for this problem does not make sense, you'll need the same lock on both reading or writing (though you might want 2 sets of conditions, one for "queue empty" and one for "queue full"  if you want to put an upper bound on the queue).

Comment: @Andreas Look into https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables

Answer (score 3):

I have an implementation using the same mutex from http://danborn.net/code/ but like I mentioned earlier since this uses a condition variable it also uses 1 mutex.

And here's the boost version, again with single mutex: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misunderstood something -- it is perfectly legal to call `pthread_cond_signal` even if no threads are waiting on that condition.

Also, in the context of multithreaded programming, calling something a "read" operation
usually implies that it does not change the state of the shared resource.  If by "read"
you really mean "remove an item from the head of the queue", that changes the state of
the queue (in other words, it's also a "write".)  It might be better to think in terms of "consumer and producer" rather than "reader and writer" for your situation.

A single mutex (to guarantee exclusive access to the queue), and two condition variables ("data available", "free space available") should be enough for your situation.  (If the
queue can grow dynamically, you won't need a "free space available" condition variable;
I just mention that for completeness.)

If your reading threads are *strictly* readers (that is, they do **not** modify the shared queue data structure in any way, such as by popping an item out of the queue), the `pthread_rwlock` family of calls may also be an appropriate solution.  In this paradigm, there are read locks (which multiple readers can hold simultaneously, but force writers to block until the readers are done), and write locks (which ensure exclusive access by the thread holding the write lock, blocking any other writers *and* readers).

Comment: Interesting thinking. Couple of points: 1) It is error to call pthread_cond_signal before pthread_cond_wait from https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables 2) I would want my read and write ops to happen in parallel so a single mutex would not work for me.

Comment: @Arpan: 1) The tutorial is simply wrong on that point.  pthreads does not require a pthread_cond_wait to be pending at the time pthread_cond_signal is called. 2) If a read and write of the same data structure are allowed to run in parallel, the reader may receive corrupt data.  This is an extremely common scenario, and using a single mutex to guarantee exclusive access is a straightforward and common solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 1). On 2) I don't see how reader could receive corrupt data -- contention between 2 readers is guarded by read mutex. If any one has locked the mutex and now polling for the queue to be non-empty this should work.

Comment: @Arpan: Multiple readers (in the strict sense, as defined above in my answer) do not need exclusive access.  Readers and writers, or multiple writers, do need to be prevented from running in parallel. Consider this scenario:  Writing thread gets interrupted partway through a non-atomic write operation, leaving the data temporarily in an inconsistent state.  At that moment, the reading thread gets scheduled, and (since there's no mutex) reads the partly-written data, getting garbage.

Comment: I've edited my answer to mention the pthread_rwlock routines, which may (or may not) be a good solution for your problem, depending on exactly what sort of operations your reading threads perform on the shared queue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a semaphore instead of a condition variable?  A semaphore is waitable and can represent a "queue is non-empty" status even when no threads are waiting.

Comment: Valid point, but a semaphore and reader/writer locks aren't quite the same: The latter is an optimization, in the case that writers are infrequent.

Answer (score 0):

A simple boost::condition example is located [here](http://www.paulbridger.com/condition_variables).